# NSFileHandle Cocoa Error 3

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

So I have a user drop some files into my application. Later I'm handling these files using NSFileHandle like this:

```
    NSFileHandle *inputFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingFromURL:path error:&error];
    if(inputFile == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error (2): %@",error);
        return;
    }
```

On my Mac it works, but on other devices this error occurs:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error 3.)" ...
```

I have looked into FoundationErrors.h but there is no error code 3 and i couldn't find anything useful using google.

What is causing this error (the description doesn't give much detail) and how can i prevent it?

Comment: Other Macs, i have enabled sandboxing, but it should allow user selected Files/Directories.

Comment: error should be an NSError object.  Have you looked at this object?

Comment: @jwlaughton That's what he's showing us at the "Error Domain" log statement. It's not routine sandboxing problem (because that generates Code=1). Very curious...

Comment: @jwlaughton the declaration for error is NSError *error = nil;

Comment: @Rob yes, every machine is running Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.1

Comment: So what is path? does it exist on every machine?

Comment: This method will return nil if no file exists at path.

Comment: You abbreviated the error log text. Why? Show the whole thing. In particular, is there an underlying error?

Comment: @tommynator128 If it's not too inconvenient, I guess I'd try temporarily turning off sandboxing and see if the problem is related to that feature, or whether there's some more fundamental file system issue. While I don't think there's anything here that you haven't seen, just in case: [Technical Q&A QA1773](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1773/_index.html).

Comment: @Rob i have tried it without sandboxing enabled, and it also did not work.